# Google Apps email alias not working?

Tags: gmail

We have multiple domains in our Google Apps (`example1.com`, `example2.com`). Emails and aliases for `example1.com` are working OK - mail sent to `user@example1.com` is redirected to `useralias@example1.com`.

I'm trying to set an alias `user@example2.com` and `info@example2.com` to be redirected to `user@example1.com` - this is an option in user settings. But the problem is that when I try to send an email it bounces back:

> Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
>   A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of 
>    its recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed...

I checked it here: http://mxtoolbox.com/ and I get this error:

```
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

EDIT:
If I send an email from a domain on our server (for example: `whateveruser@example1.com` or `whateveruser@example3.com`) to any alias at `example2.com`, it also won't be received. But from other emails on other servers it works fine.

Comment: Did you set up MX records for `example2.com`?

Comment: Yes, MX records are set up, just like for example2.com